# How to modify properties while proceeding BFS in Boost Graph Library?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, breadth-first-search

I'm using bundled property for a graph. Definitions are as follows:

```
class Node
{
    void AssignPlane(Plane& p)
    Plane* dp;
    double errors;
}

void Node::AssignPlane(Plane& p)
{
    dp=&p;
    errors=p.a+p.b+p.c;// simplified
}

typedef adjacency_list<vecS,vecS,bidirectionalS,Node,float> NGraph;

//...

struct NVisitor: default_bfs_visitor
{
    void discover_vertex(VertexDesc u, const NGraph& g) const
    {
        // CAN'T MODIFY G
    }
}
```

But I can't simply call g[u].AssignPlane(p) to modify a vertex, nor can I get the pointer to the vertex, which are both vital to me. 
Though this question may seem to be stupid, as a novice of Boost, and have fought two weeks to adapt to the convoluted style of Boost codes, I really need help. 
Do not try to answer "You need to use something other than BGL", please, as I can find nothing to support my work other than BGL. 
And I must also say, the official documentation is not intended to explain their great work in a simpler way. Since I have read the documentation for dozens of times, do not suggest me to reread the documentation. 
I will appreciate any useful help, and say thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the fields mutable

```
class Node
{
    void AssignPlane(Plane& p) const;
    Plane* mutable dp;
    double mutable errors;
}

void Node::AssignPlane(Plane& p) const
{
    dp=&p;
    errors=p.a+p.b+p.c;// simplified
}
```

Otherwise, consider holding a non-const "reference" to the graph inside the visitor:

```
struct NVisitor: default_bfs_visitor
{
    NGraph* gref_;
    NVisitor(NGraph& g) : gref_(&g) {}

    void discover_vertex(VertexDesc u, const NGraph& g) const
    {
        Plane* p = /*get it somewhere*/;
        (*gref_)[u].AssignPlane(p);
    }
}
```

Be careful not to break the invariants for BFS (like, don't edit edges while traversing).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into event visitors?

It looks like the graph is passed in by non-const reference in this example:

[Depth-First Search Event Visitor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/example/dfs_parenthesis.cpp)

[Boost Event Visitors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/EventVisitor.html)